# Struct Template in C++

Tags: c++

I have a header file,

```
class CListEx
{
public:
    CListEx();
    ~CListEx();

    void InitList();
    void AddList(char * msg);

private:

    template <typename T>
    struct MyList {
        T data;
        int num;
    };
};
```

Now in Cpp file,

```
void CListEx::InitList()
{
    MyList *my = new MyList();
}
```

And this gives error,

**E0441 argument list for class template "CListEx::MyList" is missing**

**Error C2514   'CListEx::MyList': class has no constructors**

Any ideas?

**What I TRIED:**

I tried below approach and that also gives errors.

```
template <typename T >MyList *my = new template <typename T >MyList();
```

Comment: You need a template parameter for the type of T. `new MyList<int>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message gives a very clear reason: argument list for class template is missing. Meaning, you should write some code like:

```
void CListEx::InitList()
{
    MyList<int> *my = new MyList<int>();
}
```

Read up on templates for example at: https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/templates

Comment: I have a question though. If i use INT, then will i be able to initialize MyList.data variable with a string value? 
i.e., MyList<int> *my = new MyList<int>();
       my->data = "xoxo";

Comment: @donguy76 No, for that you will need to use `MyList<std::string>` because the `T`in your template then "will be" string

Comment: Then doesn't that defeats the purpose of using templates in a struct? If i have to use a different data type for every different types of data, then shouldn't it be better to declare the struct itself with different data types?

Comment: @donguy76 If you prefer to write 10 different MyStructs (such as MyStructInt, MyStructString, MyStructFloat, MyStructEtc ... with 10 different data types they hold) then you can do it, however this was the exact purpose of inventing the templates. That one templated struct can hold N different datatypes, but needs to be written only once.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
class CListEx
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    void InitList();
private:
    template <typename T>
    struct MyList {
        T data;
        int num;
    };
};

template <typename T>
void CListEx::InitList()
{
    MyList<T> *my = new MyList<T>();
}

int main()
{
    CListEx cle;
    cle.InitList<int>();
}
```

Or are you trying to do this?

```
template <typename T>
class CListEx
{
public:
    void InitList();
private:
    struct MyList {
        T data;
        int num;
    };
};

template <typename T>
void CListEx<T>::InitList()
{
    MyList *my = new MyList();
}

int main()
{
    CListEx<int> cle;
    cle.InitList();
}
```

Beware of the memory leak. Preferably use `std::unique_prt` from `<memory>`.